# HTML page containing a GET request

Tags: html, get

All,

I have to manually create an HTML page. The story behind it is not that interesting... But in case on wonders. I want to change a GET request's parameters, for google, to enforce safe search. So I have 
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1422&bih=755&q=blabla&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=

to

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1422&bih=755&q=blabla&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&safe=strict

I have to create an HTML page with the modified get parameters.
What would that HTML string look like?

Thanks
Reza

Comment: What does the HTML page do exactly?

Comment: `strict` is not a valid value: http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html#safesp

Comment: the page forces the searches to be safe by setting safe=strict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Safe search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://google.com/search" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en" />
            <input type="hidden" name="source" value="hp" />
            <input type="hidden" name="biw" value="1422" />
            <input type="hidden" name="bih" value="755" />
            <input type="text" name="q" />
            <input type="hidden" name="aq" value="f" />
            <input type="hidden" name="aqi" value="g10" />
            <input type="hidden" name="aql" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oq" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="safe" value="strict" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Most of the parameters are unnecessary, but here is a form, containing a search field, that will produce the search query you want